# Your repository has no remotes configured to pull from (vs code). Remote exists. + git from terminal is working

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I have a problem with VS Code Ubuntu.

> Your repository has no remotes configured to pull from

However `git remote -v` gives

```
origin  https://xxx@dev.azure.com/xxx/xxx/_git/xxx (fetch)
origin  https://xxx@dev.azure.com/xxx/xxx/_git/xxxx (push)
```

When I try to add remote here:

[image: vs code source control]

I have the message that it already exists.

I reinstalled the vscode and then recloned the repository, it works half of the day, and then the problem comes back.

From the terminal git works. Not from vs code.

How to solve the problem in vs code?

Comment: Did you remove the `.vscode` directory also after the before reinstalling ? on windows its generally under user home directory. not sure of Ubuntu.

Comment: @AsifKamranMalick to remove, I use this 2 commands:
sudo apt purge code
sudo apt autoremove

Comment: not sure about Ubuntu. But [this SU post](https://superuser.com/a/1113026) will help you to find out the .vscode location. Even after uninstallation VSCode leaves behind workspace settings.

Answer (score 0):

i was getting this message as well.
So i run add remote command in terminal then it automatically knows where the remote is.So this makes it a one time hassle for one repo.

Just make a new repository and upload some small stuff and check whether that works or not.
If it works that means the problem is prolly in the repo.
Im new too and so i keep getting these types of error, im not sure but somethings related to branch or something must have happened.
If u want i can give u, all the steps to upload to git properly using vscode(but you will have to write one line only when setting a new repo).

the main problem is something to do with upstream and origin and master stuff. it is basically creating an extra branch. So check in git repo if u have a branch origin and master. i know this prolly wont solve the issue but prolly move u in some direction

**Edited from here:**

Ok no prob, let's try again
first of all lets see if your problem is the same as mine or not.

step-1: Is it happening in only one repository?
did you tried making another?
if not then first try making a dummy repo and push something.

[image]

step-2: Check this whether you have some unintended multiple branches(probably by the name of origin or master and check their default as well). If you have them then tell me ill provide the answer.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I did not get, in my terminal when I run git remote -v, I already have remote (as mentioned in the post). I cant add the same remote